# Is there an Android payment API that will let my users purchase goods on another service inside my app?

Tags: android, paypal, payment-gateway

Disclaimer, I am an absolute beginner in App-Commerce.

I want to make it easier for people to find the best prices for some goods and buy at the best price in my app.
But, I don't want to save any payment information in my app.

As an example this would be a description of the payment workflow:

1. User clicks on Buy button for Product from CompanyACME
2. My App sends identification information to User Payment API account (Paypal?)
3. My App asks Payment API account to take care about billing and payment
   processing.
4. Done

Would you know an API that would act as a intermediary for letting people pay for goods from other companies within my app?

Answer (score 0):

Try Google In App purchase API

refer this [link](https://developers.google.com/wallet/instant-buy/android/tutorial)